# Can Firebase crash reporting and crashlytics both be used

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

So firstly as we know crash reporting is being phased out and crashlytics is the new go to. I want to upgraded the latest version of our android application to use crashlytics, however an older version of the app which is in use and currently cannot be upgraded uses crash reporting.

My question is if i upgrade to crashlytics, will this break crash reporting on the older version of the application? Ideally they would both still work as at the moment releasing a new apk to replace the old version is not an option. The app is not on the play store so its not a simple upgrade process.

I was not sure if this question should be asked on firebase support or not. Thank you for any help on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think have similar experience with you.

My old android application used Firebase Crash Reportings, but then I update my app to Firebase Crashlytics.

The old app still sending crash reports, and you can still trace and monitor them by using the Crashlytics dashboard in Firebase Console. And you can keep monitoring them until Firebase Crash Reportings is really out.

But I suggest you to switch Firebase Crashlytics as soon as possible. And reach out to your users (using FCM or just manual email :)) and ask them to update your app as well.

Comment: A brilliant, i shall give it a go then. Yer the old version of the app will be phased out in the next month or so, so it will be sorted before September when they expire crash reporting. Thanks for your help.